# View revision history on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, revisions-list

It looks like it's currently not possible to view the revision history of a post from the mobile site. I think it would be a lot simpler than loading the desktop site on a phone just to get the revision history.

Comment: The mobile site is meant to be a very *limited functionality* environment. It only supports the most common things, the rest you need to switch over to the full site to use. I'm not sure why the revision history is something you're likely to use very often on a mobile device.